# SQL Query time - execution time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am carrying out the below query and it has said "Loading" for ages now. I can look at my other table within the database but when I try to look at the one I was querying it just says "Loading" , would this kind of query take long. I have about 59k records in that test_db table and 10k in the other. I am using waamp server 3.0.6 on windows 10

```
UPDATE test_db t
JOIN whisky w ON t.name=w.whisky_name
SET t.whisky_id = w.whisky_id;
```

Comment: is the a INDEX on **w.whisky_namw**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speed this query:

```
UPDATE test_db t JOIN
       whisky w
       ON t.name = w.whisky_name
    SET t.whisky_id = w.whisky_id;
```

You want an index. The optimal index is `whisky(whisky_name, whisky_id)`.  It is very important that `whisky_name` be the first key in the index.